# Auto Proxy does not work on CentOS 7.2 without giving the wpad url explicitly

Tags: linux, networking, proxy, dns, centos7

I am using proxy and my local centOS 7.2 machine needs to find that wpad file and get the proxy address in order to connect to the proxy server automatically.
This works ok, if I enter the wpad url like on the picture:

[image]

But the problem shows when this field(Configuration url) is empty.I don't know if the machine is not able to make a successful request to get this file because does not know how to put together the whole url for the wpad file or is it something else?

Or maybe this is the only way that Automatic proxy is working with explicitly telling the CentOS machine the whole wpad URL in the network configurations?